# RpcSs connects to 180.97.239.5. Should I be alarmed?

Tags: windows-7, internet, privacy, svchost, rpc

Today I found a suspicious connection from svchost.exe to 180.97.239.5.

In the Windows Task Manager I found that the connection is made from RpcSs.

According to Wikipedia, RPC is remote procedure call *when a computer program causes a procedure (subroutine) to execute in another address space (commonly on another computer on a shared network), which is coded as if it were a normal (local) procedure call, without the programmer explicitly coding the details for the remote interaction.*

IP address 180.97.239.5 is an IPv4 address owned by Chinanet-js and located in Nanjing, China.

I am not in China and I did not order remote computing.

What could this possibly mean and should I be alarmed?

Comment: There are viruses that infect rpcss.dll   Does anything come up in an AV scan?

Comment: No. Avast says: "No threat found." I wonder if a malware program could hijack rpcss without modifying it?

Answer (score 0):

Am i correct in saying your in QLD? If this is the case you have nothing to worry about this is APNIC they provide number resource allocation and registration services that support the global operation of the Internet. If RpcSs is causing you issues you can delete it and nothing will happen if you have nothing to do with APNIC.

Comment: No I am not in QLD. Actually I am about 13000 km away. Others suggest that RpcSs can not be deleted without damaging the system. And that it is a notorious security vulnerability.